# How can I hide specific user from dropdown list of users

Tags: hooks

Could you please help me with one little question. I'm using Drupal module [Support Ticketing System](https://www.drupal.org/project/support).

When the support ticket is created user can choose from dropdown form for whom this ticket is assigned. Usually it's a list of Drupal site users.

How can I hide a specific user from this list (admin for example)?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to add a new field show/hide Checkbox in account settings and then in drop down show only those whose show/hide field set to show.

This way if your client wants to hide another user go and edit the user and hide it

Comment: Interesting idea! Could you please give me a hint how to write an "if" structure with such checkboxes? Something like

Comment: Something like if ('checkbox exists') {unset($form['support']['client_dependencies']['assigned']['#options']['user id']);}

Comment: load user with $account = user_load($user_id) in and dpm($user)
You will see field for checkbox just test date.
Make sure you do this logic when you are building array for dropdown

Answer (score 0):

In your form_alter() function, run an [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) on the options array for the dropdown.

Comment: Or just unset it, something like:  `unset($form[something_here]['#options][user id]);`

Comment: Assuming it's only one, yes. But the post was talking about "list of Drupal site users".

Comment: I took it that 'How can I hide a specific user' meant one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! At the moment just one. But customer may want hide two or three or even more in future. It would be great to have a universal solution.